# WSO2 API Manager HTTPS/SSL BasesSandbox URL

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We are using WSO2 API Manager 1.9.1 as gateway to an E-Learning API solution. Our requirement includes that the Sandbox environment should be accessed using HTTPS/SSL.

One solutions, that we have found so far, is to separate Production and Sandbox modes in api-manager.xml.

My question is it possible that we can specify HTTPS/SSL based URLs, in Hybrid mode, for both Production and Sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is it possible that we can specify HTTPS/SSL based URLs,
>   in Hybrid mode, for both Production and Sandbox?

Yes, it is always possible, and the support provided out of the box.

If the backend's SSL certificate signed by a CA, you can directly specify the https url in both sandbox and production. But, if you have selfsigned certificate in the backend, you have import the public key certificate of the backend into API Manager's keystore `wso2carbon.jks` found in `<APIM_HOME>/repository/resources/security` directory

Comment: Abimaran, thanks for the reply but the problem is not related with SSL certificate.

In Hybrid mode, in api-manager.xml, if we specify HTTPS/SSL based URLs, as GatewayEndpoint, for both Sandbox and Production, WSO2 API Manager pickks up the last URL and displayed it as a single URL for both Sandbox and Production. It seems that, in Hybrid mode, WSO2 classify both Sandbox and Production URLs using the HTTP and HTTPS respectively.

Comment: Following is the test setting that I did in api-manager.xml in order to test if we can specify HTTPS based URLs as GatewayEndpoint for both Sandbox and Production. On WSO2 Store, the last url i.e https://localhost:9443 is displayed for both Sandbox and Production and the URL that we specify first , i.e https://localhost:8443 is ignored.

    <Environment type="hybrid" api-console="true">
  <Name>Production and Sandbox</Name>
  ........
  <GatewayEndpoint>
   https://localhost:8443,https://localhost:9443
  </GatewayEndpoint>
 </Environment>